# Работа с array.map

Tags: javascript

Как прописать, что если item равно noga, то мы заменяем предыдущее значение. То есть в данном случае ruka станет другая строка
Сделать это именно c array.map. То есть, допустим, таких мест в массиве будет несколько.

```js
var relax = ["noc", "ruka", "noga", "golova", "stypny"]
  var lis = relax.map(function(item, index){
    return item = 'noga' ? item = 'другая строка' : item;
  })
  console.log(lis);
```

Comment: почему только `map`?

Comment: Просто спортивный интерес. Это не конкретная задача, изучаю JS и просто интересно

Answer (score 0):

Странная идея делать это с помощью map, но

```js
var relax = ["noc", "ruka", "noga", "golova", "stypny"]
var lis = relax.map((item, index, array) => 
    array[index + 1] == 'noga' ? 'другая строка' : item
)
console.log(lis);
```

Comment: Я только начинаю изучать JS. Подскажите почему это плохая идея делать это через array_map? Как бы вы решали эту задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Если просто ради спортивного интереса то так:

```js
var relax = ["noc", "ruka", "noga", "golova", "stypny"]
var lis = relax.map(function(item, index, arr){
    return (arr.length - 1) > index && arr[index + 1] === 'noga' ? 'другая строка' : item;
});
console.log(lis)
```